# In PHP, is there a short way to compare a variable to multiple values?

Tags: php, variables, comparison, shorthand

Basically what I'm wondering if there is a way to shorten something like this:

```
if ($variable == "one" || $variable == "two" || $variable == "three")
```

in such a way that the variable can be tested against or compared with multiple values without repeating the variable and operator every time.

For example, something along the lines of this might help:

```
if ($variable == "one" or "two" or "three")
```

or anything that results in less typing.

Comment: I realized that after I posted.  Thanks for the tip, of course!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is what I use

```
if (in_array($variable, array('one','two','three'))) {
```

Comment: always too fast for me John Conde :P

Comment: I did realize this after I posted my question.  Guess I jumped the gun.  This is a rather brilliant solution and particularly helpful when comparing to several things at once.  Thank you.  I'll accept it once the site lets me.  It says I have to wait.

Comment: @brbcoding, I still appreciate your efforts.

Comment: shorter: `if (in_array($variable, ['one','two','three'])) {`

Comment: how would you handle this with an AND `&&` situation?

Answer (score 4):

Without the need of constructing an array:

```
if (strstr('onetwothree', $variable))
//or case-insensitive => stristr
```

Of course, technically, this will return true if variable is `twothr`, so adding "delimiters" might be handy:

```
if (stristr('one/two/three', $variable))//or comma's or somehting else
```

Comment: I think you have a typo and meant to say "twothr" instead of "thothr", but obviously I know what you meant.  At any rate, this is another nice tactic, and in fact, is even shorter.  I noticed you used `strstr` the first time and `stristr` the second time.  What is the difference?

Comment: `strstr` looks for an _exact_ string match (CaseSensitive) `stristr` with the `i` performs a case-insensiteve comparison. that's the only difference. And yes, that tothr rubbish was a typo :P

Comment: Ah, okay.  That's what I thought the difference was.  Also 'thwothr' is still a typo XD

Comment: @vertigoelectric: aw nips... I just can't seem to get it together today ;)

Comment: Unfortunately that's not enough: this will still approve a value such as "ree" or "wo". You would need to use `"/{$variable}/"` instead of `$variable`. While probably slower, the `in_array` solution starts to appear cleaner.

Comment: @LSerni: in this case one would need a string like '/one/two/three/', so the first and last fit as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$variable = 'one';
// ofc you could put the whole list in the in_array() 
$list = ['one','two','three'];
if(in_array($variable,$list)){      
    echo "yep";     
} else {   
    echo "nope";        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With switch case

```
switch($variable){
 case 'one': case 'two': case 'three':
   //do something amazing here
 break;
 default:
   //throw new Exception("You are not worth it");
 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_grep` could be shorter and more flexible than using `in_array`:

```
if (preg_grep("/(one|two|three)/i", array($variable))) {
  // ...
}
```

Because the optional `i` [pattern modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (**i**nsensitive) can match both upper and lower case letters.