# Is there PHP shorthand for testing variable value for multiple conditions without using in_array?

Tags: php, ternary, shorthand

I find myself doing this a lot, and I assume there is a short hand way to make this faster. Yet in my research about shorthand and ternary operations, I can't quite seem to wrap my head around how to do it.

```
// below variable only be impactful if it's SET, not Null, and === important value.

$verbose_instructively_named_variable = $other_variable. "_modifier";

if(isset($verbose_instructively_named_variable) && $verbose_instructively_named_variable !== null && $verbose_instructively_named_variable === "key_text_modifier"):
     // Now do important thing here;
endif;
```

I am a beginning programmer obviously, but find myself attracted to longer variable names so when I revisit things later it flows linearly for me. So I find myself wanting to do the below all the time, and am frustrated I can't.

```
if(isset($verbose_instructively_named_variable) && !==null && === "key_text_modifier"):
     // Now do important stuff;
endif;
```

I know this is a PHP question, but I find myself wanting this form of chained logic in javascript also. Am I missing a basic step of some kind?

Is there an altogether different way to test ONE variable for multiple conditions quickly and efficiently?

I have tried combinations of things found in similar questions. Like the in_array solution provided in this answer: [In PHP, is there a short way to compare a variable to multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345833/in-php-is-there-a-short-way-to-compare-a-variable-to-multiple-values)

As well as things like the below standard shortcut/shorthand.

```
$result = $initial ?: 'default';
```

But what I want often is something more like this.

```
$result = ($initial !==null && !=="bad" && !in_array($initial,$record_set_from_mysql_query) ? $initial : 'default');
```

And keep in mind the main reason I don't like and don't want to do this:

```
$result = ($initial !==null && $initial !=="bad" $initial !=="even_worse" ? $initial : 'default');
```

Is because "$initial" maybe named something like $always_make_this_value_green_when_blue_present or something otherwise cumbersome to type repeatedly and it makes the code hard to read later with multi-line parameters in the functions etc.

Presently my best work around for this is to do this.

```
$a = $long_verbose_instructively_named_variable;
$result = $a !== null && $a !== "bad" && $a !== "even_worse" ? $a : 'default';
```

But this means in a function with a half dozen little small if/else checks I end up with a, aa, aaa, a_4, a_5 variables all over the place and it just gets cumbersome.

Comment: One thing that will help you and others following you - learn to be more concise with variable names.  They may sound goof, but it soon becomes a real PITA!

Comment: For such cases I prefer the [match() statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php).

Comment: Are these half a dozen or so if/else checks looking for the same conditions, but with different variables? Maybe you should consolidate these checks into a helper function that you can pass the variable to check and the values to check against. Even if the code for this function is verbose/repetitive, at least you're only doing it in *one* place rather than a half dozen places.

Comment: I think @NigelRen advice looms large in my brain. Thanks for the motivation, Nigel! I just find my 50 year old brain less able to remember things a week later and when I revisit classes that I haven't seen in a few days or weeks it helps me to be able to know based on the name what is happening. :)

Comment: @MarkusZeller I think you may have helped me greatly! I had been aware of the match() statement but never really logged its usefulness to the best part of my brain! I think this will do the trick most of the time. Thanks. If you submit your comment as an answer I will mark it as my solution.

Comment: `isset($verbose_instructively_named_variable) && !==null` doesn't make sense because `isset()` does not return `true` when the value of the variable is `null`.  We don't have a realistic [mcve] here, so I don't know if I can advice the use of a lookup array -- using keys to identify blacklisted values may allow you to use `isset($var) && !isset($blacklist[$var])` which will perform better than a call of `in_array()`.  Then again, if your blacklist is relatively small, this microoptimization will not be worth worrying about.

Answer (score 0):

I will still recommend you use in_array at this point. When the array is not big enough, the speed of in_array is still good enough. Because your code will be more easier to read.

As Markus Zeller commented, you can also use a match() method at this condition, you can read from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php).

PHP also support array key with characters, it's mean you can use isset() method for your problem, you can read on [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

A tips, you may read [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/).

Comment: My issue in my real coding as opposed to my simplest example to communicate my point, is that the array I must create to make in_array work, usually is just as long as any other thing I could type. I just wish there was protocol in the short-hand that knew if I don't specify anything else on the left, I am wanting to always compare back to it type thing... like if(a=b || c || d || e): // then do some stuff.

Comment: you can use in_array for null too. so if(a=b || c || d || e) you can use `if(in_array(a, [b,c,d,e]))`. 

if you want to make ($initial !==null && $initial !=="bad" $initial !=="even_worse") to in_array, you can go it with `if(!in_array($initial, [null, "bad", "even_worse"])`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tradeoff between legible code that may be more verbose, and clever code that is shorter but harder to understand. That being said, this is a bit of a kludge but seems to achieve your goal of only referencing `$long_verbose_instructively_named_variable` once:

```
switch ($result = ($long_verbose_instructively_named_variable ?? 'default')) {
    case 'bad':
    case 'even_worse':
        $result = 'default';
}
```

The results for various test cases:

```
For [unset] got 'default'
For false got false
For NULL got 'default'
For 'bad' got 'default'
For 'even_worse' got 'default'
For 'foo' got 'foo'
```

How I generated these test cases:

```
$test_cases = [ FALSE, NULL, 'bad', 'even_worse', 'foo' ];

for ( $i=-1; $i < sizeof($test_cases); $i++ ) {
    if ( -1 == $i ) {
        unset($long_verbose_instructively_named_variable);
    } else {
        $long_verbose_instructively_named_variable = $test_cases[$i];
    }

    echo "For " . ( (-1 == $i ) ? '[unset]' : var_export($long_verbose_instructively_named_variable, TRUE) );

    switch ($result = ($long_verbose_instructively_named_variable ?? 'default')) {
        case 'bad':
        case 'even_worse':
            $result = 'default';
    }

    echo " got " . var_export($result, TRUE) . "\n";
}
```